# Filtering django foreignkey dropdown relative to other field in same model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

So essentially I'm using django-nested-admin to create a "quiz" type model where the admin can add custom questions and answers to those questions. The issue now is that the admin view can't distinguish which answers belong to which questions, so everytime a user goes to select an answer choice, they are able to select from every answer for every question ever created. I've included a photo of what this looks like from the admin.

I've tried overriding the formfield_foreign_key form for the admin, and have been able to filter the shown answer choices by hardcoding a question id. However, I want to be able to filter the answers based on the question associated with the response and am having trouble doing so. Can anybody provide any insight? Thanks in advance.

[Answers all mixed up in response admin view:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTlOW.png)

[Answers filtered via a hardcoded id:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6SFd.png)

Current code which filters based on hardcoded question_id:

```
class ResponseInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Response

   def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "answer":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Answer.objects.filter(question_id = 1)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

My current Response model in models.py:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    question_form = models.ForeignKey(AdditionalQuestions, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.label
```

Comment: You try to accomplish multiple use scenarios in one view it´s better to seperate your functionality to separate views. Besides that User´s should not access your admin. What kind of Quiz that? Can the user give an answer in an textfield or choose between choices? If you only want to display the user,question,answer (in one seperate line per data entry) try to customize your admin view in `admin.py` with `list_display`. But the best way is to  better create a single views in your normal app.

Comment: you need to consider redesign your scenario